# Quick books online Api. Entity fields for store our firm information

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are using the sdk .net api and want to store service information for few Intuit entities (for example, bill and customer). Information about the identifiers of our offices, etc (json string if possible). Which entity fields we can use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuit documents all available fields on their website - go look at their documentation:

- Customers: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/customer
- Bills: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/bill

You should store data in whatever field is appropriate. Custom fields are available if you have data that doesn't fit well in any existing field:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/create-custom-fields

All fields are user-facing, so it *would not* be recommended to store JSON-encoded string blobs within QuickBooks (it will likely be very confusing to whoever is using QuickBooks, and they will be able to change that data to an invalid JSON string). You should probably be keeping that JSON data in your own app, not in QuickBooks.

Comment: Hi Keith! Thank you for your answer. I wanted to add custom fields for our data, but I can't add custom fields with use api, only with Intuit web interface. We try to create integration for our client, and need to add service data in auto mode. This solution does not suit us. I found IntuitAnyType in all entities. What do you think about this field?

Comment: IntuitAnyType is just a helper class, it doesn't actually exist as anything in the REST API/in QuickBooks itself. 

Correct, you cannot create custom fields via the API. If you feel you need to, you're probably doing something wrong or need to revisit the requirements for your client. There is very, very rarely a need to do this.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I will rethinking my approach.